# Excel: Delete Last Word In String IF it is a number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I can't find any answers anywhere that do what I need... :(

Basically I have a bunch of product titles, some with a number (SKU) at the end, some with not.

All SKUS will end with a number. In Pseudo: IF the last character of the last word is a number, remove the last word. - *This isn't actually a word but a number.*

Here is an example: "Medium Racer Back Top And Short Lounge Set **7091**" (I want to delete the bold part if the last character is a number)

As always, thanks in advance for any help :)

D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex to replace the end numbers. Use pattern `"\s\d+$"` to get rid of white space at end.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Debug.Print GetString("Medium Racer Back Top And Short Lounge Set 7091")

End Sub

Public Function GetString(ByVal inputString As String) As Variant
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "[^\s]\d+$"    '<==  \s\d+$   '<==to remove white space at end as well
        If .test(inputString) Then
            GetString = .Replace(inputString, vbNullString)
        Else
            GetString = inputString
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

---

**Used as User Defined Function in sheet:**

[image]

---

**Regex:**

[Try it](https://regex101.com/r/VtqUzt/1/)

```
[^\s]\d+$
```

Match a single character not present in the list below [^\s]

`\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])

`\d+` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

`+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you for the extra information and the time you took to explain what each part does! I really appreciate it :) D